# Yahoo Web Analytics Upgrade

Tags: javascript, analytics, yahoo-analytics

Yahoo is forcing an upgrade to their current version of Yahoo Web Analytics tracking code (from version 4 to version 5).  The deadline for upgrading is the end of this month. Here is the message within the interface:

> In 2009, we migrated all of our client
>   accounts to a new Data Center in order
>   to improving the overall security and
>   reliability of our service and come in
>   line with the high standards of
>   security and service demanded by
>   Yahoo!. At that time, we introduced a
>   new version of the Yahoo! Web
>   Analytics tracking code (version 5).
>   Please note that support for version 4
>   of the YWA tracking code will cease on
>   July 30th 2010. Please visit our Help
>   Center should you have any questions
>   about using version 5 of the tracking
>   code. Our Installation Guide for
>   Version 5 may be downloaded from here

I have looked at the version 4 versus version 5 image requests and parameters sent to their servers and it's still the same server and parameters, so I don't really see why they *need* to enforce this.

Also, I talked to someone who said their Yahoo Account Manager said that Yahoo does not plan on actually enforcing this.  Can anybody confirm this or know anything about this?  I just found out about this and I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to upgrade my website's code in time (I have multiple websites with very complex implementation....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their [blog entry](http://www.yanalyticsblog.com/blog/2010/07/v-4-tracking-code-migration-deadline-is-approaching/) says:

> Please note that when v.4 support ends YWA will continue to track sites utilizing this code but going forward there will be no updates, bug fixes or technical support for that version.

They also have a free tool called [No Tags, No Glory](http://www.notagsnoglory.com/2010/05/30/free-ywa-tracking-code-check/) to help you detect legacy code.

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

just want to clarify some items (FYI - I work for Yahoo! Web Analytics).
1) No Tags, No Glory is not a tool produced by us but by a member of the Yahoo! Web Analytics Consultant Network.
2) We originally had IndexTools code and then following the acquisition by Yahoo! we remodelled the code to version 5.  On July 30th, support for version 4 of the tracking code will be discontinued.  This means that the support team will not be in a position to answer queries for customers with version 4 and there will be no bug fixes, updates to version 4 code.  Tracking will continue however.
3) There are elements of data collection that will only work with version 5 and as time goes on, the data value gap between version 4 and 5 will grow.
Hope that helps!
Emer